# Asynchronous updates only show 1 value

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask-socketio

Referenced from: 
https://www.shanelynn.ie/asynchronous-updates-to-a-webpage-with-flask-and-socket-io/

I am altering this code to work with load cells and display on a web page continuously. All works great and the correct code is shown on the web page, however I only want the most recent value to display on the web page, not 10 values at a time. At first I thought this would be in the static/js/application.js file but altering that code does not solve the problem. I'm not sure where the div id="log" is being defined, if this is where the issue is coming into play. Any help is appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //connect to the socket server.
    var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/test');
    var numbers_received = [];

    //receive details from server
    socket.on('newnumber', function(msg) {
        console.log("Received number" + msg.number);
        //maintain a list of ten numbers
        if (numbers_received.length >= 10){
            numbers_received.shift()
        }            
        numbers_received.push(msg.number);
        numbers_string = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < numbers_received.length; i++){
            numbers_string = numbers_string + '<p>' + numbers_received[i].toString() + '</p>';
        }
        $('#log').html(numbers_string);
    });

});
```

I atempted changing the "maintain a list of ten numbers" code (changed the 10 to other values, commented out) but nothing changed on the output.

Comment: You should include the code that you have. It'll make it easier to tell you where is the mistake. You are correct in that the application.js file is where the last 10 numbers are collected and formatted, so the change does need to be in that file.

Comment: Added the application.js code and mentioned what I have tried, I have yet to come up with a valid solution

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //connect to the socket server.
    var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/test');
    var numbers_received = [];

    //receive details from server
    socket.on('newnumber', function(msg) {
        console.log("Received number" + msg.number);
        $('#log').html(msg.number.toString());
    });

});
```